# How to stop a timer countdown at 0. Swift

Tags: xcode, swift

Does anyone know how I can tell the timer to stop when it reaches 0. Right now it keeps counting down below zero.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var timerCount = 20
    var timerRunning = false
    var timer = NSTimer()

    @IBOutlet weak var timerLabel: UILabel!

    func Counting() {
        timerCount -= 1
        timerLabel.text = "\(timerCount)"
    }

    @IBAction func startButton(sender: UIButton) {
        if timerRunning == false {
            timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: Selector ("Counting"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
            timerRunning = true
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        if timerCount == 0 {
            timerRunning = false
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Also, some additional advice: keep local state to a minimum. You can get rid of the `timerRunning` variable because that state is already in the `NSTimer` via its `valid` property.

It simplifies code and results in less state errors if there is only a single place there you look.

Comment: Thanks ! I appreciate the advice.

Answer (score 6):

Change your `Counting` function to this:

```
func Counting() {
    timerCount -= 1
    timerLabel.text = "\(timerCount)"
    if timerCount == 0 {
        timer.invalidate()
        timerRunning = false
    }
}
```

From the [NSTimer documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSTimer/invalidate):

> ## Stopping a Timer
>
> `invalidate()`
>
> Stops the receiver from ever firing again and requests its removal from its run loop.
>
> ### Discussion
>
> This method is the only way to remove a timer from an NSRunLoop object. The NSRunLoop object removes its strong reference to the timer, either just before the invalidate method returns or at some later point.
>
> If it was configured with target and user info objects, the receiver removes its strong references to those objects as well.
>
> ### Special Considerations
>
> You must send this message from the thread on which the timer was installed. If you send this message from another thread, the input source associated with the timer may not be removed from its run loop, which could prevent the thread from exiting properly.

Comment: I have another question. Now, when it reaches 0 it does stop, but when I press start again it goes below 0 and keeps on going. How can disable that?

Comment: @MilesH. Reset the counter when the start button is pressed. Right before you start the timer do `timerCount = 20`